# Ruby on Rails OpenSSL HMAC Equivalent to VB.NET/C# HMAC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vb.net

I'm running into a problem where I cannot get the Hash value from VB.Net to match the hash value in Ruby on Rails. I'm wondering if this is almost the equivalent way to do it. The problem relies in my VB code.

Here's an example of the code:

Ruby

```
key = 'key'
data = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
digest = OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.new 
hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, key, data)
```

VB.Net

```
Dim key As String = "key"
Dim value As String = ""

Function getMD5Hash(ByVal input As String) As String
    Dim md5Hasher As New HMACMD5()
    Dim data As Byte() = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input))
    Dim sBuilder As New StringBuilder()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To data.Length - 1
        sBuilder.Append(data(i).ToString("x2"))
    Next i
    Return sBuilder.ToString()
End Function

Private Sub Test()
    Dim data As String = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
    value = getMD5Hash(key + data)
    testing.Text = value
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles testBtn.Click
    Test()
End Sub
```

Comment: Does ruby use the equivalent to .net's default encoding? try using different encoders, ASCII or UTF8.

Comment: I actually figure it out, you have to convert the key into a byte array and encode it. Then pass it into the hmacmd5 to hash it.

Comment: Glad yo got it working. Add your solution as an answer, that will help other people in the same situation.

Comment: Include the Key inside the function and convert the string into a byte array. Down below is the solution:

Function getMD5Hash(ByVal input As String) As String
Dim key As String = "key"
Dim keybyte As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)
Dim md5Hasher As New HMACMD5(keybyte)

Comment: Post it as an answer.